# Is it good practice to have multiple keyspaces in Cassandra?

Tags: database-design, replication, clustering, nosql, cassandra

I've Cassandra configured on **Amazon EC2** having **3 nodes(instances)** in **single cluster**. Now what I want to do is give some space on Cassandra to my clients by creating separate **keyspace** for each in a **single cluster**. Number of clients will increase day by day so there is no fix number of keyspaces I can assume to be created.

Will there be a performance issue if I create too many keyspaces in single cluster?

If it's not good practice, then Is there any other workaround to fit my need? I don't want to configure multiple instances of Cassandra.

If Cassandra is not the right choice for this kind of architecture, any other NoSQL database which fits my needs and How?